# Fix page scrolling when modifying text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a main page, and then other elements below that. This main page (a `div`) has a set height of `80vh`. Below that, there is one `hr` element, and one `div` element. This div elements contains some information.

On my main page, there is a title that gets modified by javascript code. At a low screen width, this causes the text to go from one to two lines. The height of the element the title is inside of remains the same due to the set `80vh`, but the page still scrolls up when the text goes **from two to one** lines. I can see that change by printing out the `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. It changes by exactly the height of one line.

How can I prevent that scrolling?

I can "fix" it by getting the `scrollTop` before changing the text and then setting the `scrollTop` to the previous value after changing it, but I would prefer a cleaner, less hacky fix.

I checked all the heights of the elements using dev tools and JavaScript code, they remain the same.

The general layout of my HTML and the part of the CSS that I think is most important:

```css
html {
  background-color: #F76E2A;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#top-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #222327;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 7px #F76E2A;
}

#home-page {
  height: 80vh;
}

hr {
  height: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  color: #222327;
  background-color: #222327;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 3rem auto
}

#projects-showcase {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">stuff</div>
<div id="home-page">the title that changes size</div>
<hr>
<div id="projects-showcase">The elements that contain information</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with scroll anchoring. Due to the #title element changing in size, the website scrolled to compensate, even though it's not supposed to do that.

To fix this, I added

```css
overflow-anchor: none;
```

to my home-page element. This prevents the page from scrolling when it isn't supposed to.